# How can I do a select into without getting duplicate columns?

Tags: sql

Say I have 200 columns in a table A, 200 columns in table B, 200 columns in table C, 200 columns in table D, 200 columns in table E, 200 columns in table F, and 200 columns in table G

Now say 190 of these columns have the same name in every table, but the other 10 are different for every table.

How can I create a new table that has 250 columns(190 that are common to all tables + the 10 other columns that are in table A + the 10 other columns that are in table B + the 10 other columns that are in table C, etc)?

I was trying to do this:

```
select Top 1 * into Master_Table 
from vw_A
cross join vw_B
cross join vw_C
cross join vw_D
cross join vw_E
cross join vw_F
cross join vw_G
```

but am getting this error:

```
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'CustomerVehicleID'     in table 'Master_Table' is specified more than once.
```

Comment: Sorry, you're gonna have to write the column names out or use dynamic sql...

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Dynamic sql` plus `information_schema.column` to get the distinct column list. something like this.

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql  NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @cols += column_name + ','
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY column_name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))    rn,
               TABLE_NAME+'.'+COLUMN_NAME  AS Column_name
        FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE  TABLE_NAME IN ( 'vw_A', 'vw_B', 'vw_C', 'vw_D',
                               'vw_E', 'vw_F', 'vw_G' )) a
where rn=1

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

SET @sql ='select Top 1 ' + @cols + ' into Master_Table 
            from vw_A
            cross join vw_B
            cross join vw_C
            cross join vw_D
            cross join vw_E
            cross join vw_F
            cross join vw_G' 

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get this error on every field. --- Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CustomerVehicleID.vw_A" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CustomerID.vw_A" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Comment: @user3442990 - try now again there was a mistake

Comment: Now I get the original error again. ---"Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'CustomerVehicleID' in table 'Master_Table' is specified more than once."

Comment: @user3442990 - missed to add the filter `where rn=1`. Problem is i don't have `SSMS` to validate the query. Try now

Answer (score 0):

You can include in the `SELECT` clause all the columns of one table (`vw_A.*`) and from the other tables only the columns that does not appear in the definition of `vw_A`:

```
select Top 1 vw_A.*,
    # columns of vw_B that do not exist in vw_A
    colB1, colB2, colB3, colB4,
    # columns of vw_C that do not exist in vw_A
    colC1, colC2, colC3, colC4,
    # columns of vw_D that do not exist in vw_A
    colD1, colD2, colD3, colD4,
    #
    # and so on
    #
into Master_Table 
from vw_A
cross join vw_B
cross join vw_C
cross join vw_D
cross join vw_E
cross join vw_F
cross join vw_G
```